# set conditions to two fields in django rest model

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is one of my model, which has only two fields

```
class Exams(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(ExamModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

before creating a new row, I want to make sure that there is no other field with the same two field values

ie.,  there may be fields like

`{"student": 1, "exam": 1}, {"student": 2, "exam": 1}, {"student": 2, "exam": 2}, {"student": 1, "exam": 2}`

but there should not be fields like

`{"student":1, "exam":1}, {"student":1, "exam":1}`

**or simply not duplicated fields should be generated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) at the model level:

```
class Exams(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(ExamModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('student', 'exam'),)
```

Besides that, Django Rest Framework also has a [`UniqueTogetherValidator`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator) that you can define in your serializer.